# Trying to use lm() in r with the year

Tags: r, lm

My data set:

```
structure(list(year = 2010:2019, pop = c(9574323, 9657592, 9749476, 
9843336, 9932887, 10031646, 10154788, 10268233, 10381615, 10488084
), ye = 1:10), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
```

I only the linear regression of the Year and Pop columns. When I run the summary(lm) for those two columns this is what I get:

```
> summary(lm(pop~year, data = this))

Call:
lm(formula = pop ~ year, data = this)

Residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-27821.4 -10094.9    656.5  12968.3  27549.8 

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -196556312    4240960  -46.35 5.19e-11 ***
year            102539       2105   48.71 3.49e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 19120 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9966,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9962 
F-statistic:  2372 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 3.493e-11
```

The slope intercept equation is not correct. But when I run the lm using the ye column, its correct.

> summary(lm(pop~ye, data = this))

```
Call:
lm(formula = pop ~ ye, data = this)

Residuals:
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-27821.4 -10094.9    656.5  12968.3  27549.8 

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  9444234      13062  723.00  < 2e-16 ***
ye            102539       2105   48.71 3.49e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 19120 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9966,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9962 
F-statistic:  2372 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 3.493e-11
```

This isn't what I'm looking for because I want to predict for the years 2020, 2021 and so on. What do I need to change to make the Year column work in the equation? I tried this in excel too, and its the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `predict`.

```
model <- lm(pop~year, data = this)
predict(model,data.frame(year=c(2020,2021)))
       1        2 
10572162 10674701
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/121911) from Cross Validated covers your question in great detail, but the short answer is the two are equivalent, except for the intercept term.

For interpretability, you might want to set a reference year, then set the regression's year data based on that reference year (e.g. 2010 = reference year 0, 2015 = year 5), much like you've done with the `ye` column.

The other commenter suggests using `predict()` to predict years 2020 and 2021, which would work for both methods (either using `c(2020, 2021)` or `c(20, 21)` respectively).

Comment: Thank you very much